# Multiple DC's in the krb5.conf realms

Tags: 16.04, kerberos

I have the following configuration in my `/etc/krb5.conf` (note this is only part of the config):

```
[libdefaults]
   ticket_lifetime = 24h
   default_realm = HQ.LOCAL
   forwardable = true

[realms]
   HQ.LOCAL = {
     hq = 192.168.100.2
     default_domain = hq.local
   }

[domain_realm]
   .hq.local = HQ.LOCAL
   hq.local = HQ.LOCAL
```

My question is this. I have 2 domain controllers, one at 192.168.100.2 and the other at 192.168.100.20

I'd like to have my [realms] be able to support more than one DC if possible.

How would I go about configuring this in this file?